# Basic file uploading in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a solution to uploading a file to a folder in Rails.

I have a file that I need to upload to a specific folder in the app 'public/uploads' with a specific name.  Each time i upload, i need to run a pre-existing background job, which will remove the file after it's done.

If it happens that a file already exists, it should just overwrite it.

I can't find a solution that covers this.  All the examples are things about attaching a file to an instance of a model and storing it in my DB.  I don't need that. That's overkill for my scenario.

Just upload file to a folder, simple as.

Suggestions?

Comment: Read the manual. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: @max I did do that before commenting here. I posted here as a last resort.  I did see that snippet at that link but couldn't quite understand the code.  Eg: Why is File.open followed by File.write?  What's is being written?   I'm a bit confused with it. Just need a bit of explanation to help me out.

Comment: ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile is a thin wrapper around a Tempfile instance which is created from the binary part of the form submission. Since tempfiles are unlinked when they are garbage collected the contents is being written to another file.

Comment: "The following snippet saves the uploaded file in #{Rails.root}/public/uploads under the same name as the original file." Original file meaning the name of the file passed by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the file path. The easiest strategy is to add a randomly generated or sequential subfolder/filename prefix for each upload.

So `Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_file.original_filename)` becomes `Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', "#{my_random_value}-#{uploaded_file.original_filename}")`.